# How to sync installed addons from opera addons?

Tags: browser, browser-addons, opera

How to sync installed addons from opera addons who i have installed like chrome does? I have installed opera addons on opera but how to sync them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way to do the same you're used to in Chrome (sync starts the very moment you login using a Google account) or Firefox (sync is enabled with a Firefox/Mozilla account) in Opera yet.

But backing up the user profile and then "restoring" it to the new installation is easy enough: https://help.opera.com/en/latest/crashes-and-issues/#backup

> Locating your files is the first step. Go to About Opera, or go to opera:about/ to find the exact paths for your profile and data folders.